# small Linux host for virtual box

Tags: distribution-choice, virtualbox, small-distribution

Does anybody know a small and simple Linux distribution that contains not much more than the "VirtualBox" program? 
I'd like to set up a machine that actually needs some kind of graphical display plus VirtualBox, which should automatically boot the productive OS as a virtual system.

Answer (score 6):

You can try http://www.slitaz.org and just get virtualbox package which should come with all its dependencies.

Comment: I also love Slitaz, its my preferred x86 light distro.